# Inherit global value from parent thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is there a way for a child thread to inherit global value from its parent thread? I know about dynamic initialization of static, thread local variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23558302/3214670, but it's no real inheritance - in this example threads created from within threads won't get their parents values, but rather value set in main.

So I have a code like below. Can anyone tell how to make child threads have the same global value as their parents?

Thread are created like this:

```
                        main thread
                        |         |
                       t1         t2
                        |         |
                      t11         t22
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

static int g = 1;
static thread_local int s = g;

std::mutex m;

void print(int i)
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> u(m);
  std::cout << "thread " << i << " s = " << s << std::endl;
}

void bar(int i)
{
  print(i);
}

void foo(int i)
{
  print(i);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
  std::thread c(bar, 11*i);
  c.join();
}

int main()
{
  std::thread a(foo, 1);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  g = 2;
  std::thread b(foo, 2);

  a.join();
  b.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
thread 1 s = 1
thread 2 s = 2
thread 11 s = 2
thread 22 s = 2
```

Output I want is:

```
thread 1 s = 1
thread 2 s = 2
thread 11 s = 1
thread 22 s = 2
```

Please note that I don't want to pass any variables to threads, but rather use global variable.

Comment: You must simply pass the information to the new thread. Using globals to communicate is fraught with dangers even in non-threaded code, it's asking for trouble. Using them to communicate between threads is like shouting and screaming at highest voice possible, for trouble.

Comment: What do you mean inherit a global value? Global variables are exactly that, **global**, by definition they are shared among all threads. At the point in time where thread 11's `s` is initialized `g` happens to have the value 2 so that's what will be used.

Comment: The thing is that I work in a huge project, where passing this value to all created threads/changing methods interfaces is not an option. Anyway, I am curious whether solution to such problem exists using global data.

Comment: I ended up by creating `s` as non-static member of a class that contains `print()`.  The controller e.g. `main()` has responsibility to set the `s` variable.  It may be not possible for your case though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible for a simple reason: There is no parent-child relationship between threads.

There are multiple workarounds, like for example building such an inheritance tree yourself, but this means that you will also have to maintain this tree. This means that whenever you start a thread, you will have to create a new entry for the new thread in the tree and whenever a thread finishes, you have to remove the according entry. This presents a bunch of problems, because firstly you must do so in a thread-safe way (avoiding race conditions). Secondly, you have to do that every time a thread is started or stopped, which effectively means you have to adjust every place a thread is started. Some of those places may even be outside of your control. Alternatively, you could try to find an OS-specific hook to track thread creation and destruction, but C++ itself doesn't provide one to you.

In summary, I'd suggest you rethink your design. Not only is the use of pseudo-globals a maintenance nightmare, your approach is also hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to add a new style of `thread_local` initialization, and there's no built-in sense of inheritance or `fork`ing.

It's possible, if you code it yourself. Just be careful about synchronization. The parent thread can't change its source values until the child thread is finished reading them. (Already this would present a problem to `thread_local` variables: they're initialized lazily upon access, not all at once upon thread initialization.)

One idiom which predates `thread_local` is to encapsulate the thread handle in a class together with thread-local state. The parent thread object can simply clone itself using its copy constructor, before launching the clone as a child. Then, all the state is ready before the child starts, so no synchronization is necessary.

In that idiom, a pointer to the thread class would be passed to the new thread function. It's not clear why `foo` cannot take a pointer argument; that's very unusual.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you have normal global variables shared by all threads, and thread_local variables which are local per-thread.

Your request is somehow a mix between the two: If I understood correctly, you want a per-thread global variable at the first level, but which become shared for second level. This is simply contradictory, you could of course make code which is compliant with your requirement, but not using the tool you ask for.
To make the point a bit more apparent: is like asking for a global variable which is only global for odd iteration of a loop.

But, there are different solution that provide you the required result. Following I made a few changes to your code for this purpose:

**Not good code example, using global to provide the required result:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>

static std::atomic<int> g;
static thread_local int s = g;

std::mutex m;

void print(int i)
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> u(m);
  std::cout << "thread " << i << " s = " << s << std::endl;
}

void bar(int i)
{
  print(i);
}

void foo(int i)
{
  print(i);
  int myVal;
  myVal= g;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
  g=myVal; // Not really good code anyway.
  std::thread c(bar, 11*i);
  c.join();
}

int main()
{
  g=1;
  std::thread a(foo, 1);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  g = 2;
  std::thread b(foo, 2);

  a.join();
  b.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Consider that this solution is a sample, for sure there are improvement to do.

**I would recommend you the same that other already did: Pass the `s` value as a parameter to `thread 11` and `thread 22`**